# to generate random number in contrast with progress bar

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display randome numbers in association with progress bar. I have 2 progress bar and 2 labelbox. When the first progress bar completes to 100% the corresponding labelbox should display the random number by using the function and the the second progress bar should start. Once the second progress bar completes to 100% the corresponding lablebox should show the random number.
I have a code but it is first processing both the progress bar and then displaying both the random numbers. I want to do one at a time. That is 1st progress bar and 1st labelbox first then 2nd progress bar and 2nd labelbox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        progressBar2.Visible = false;




    }

    Random rnd = new Random();
    private void random1()
    {

        int t = rnd.Next(200);
        label1.Text = t.ToString();

    }
    private void random2()
    {
        int t = rnd.Next(1500);
        label2.Text = t.ToString();

     }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int i;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 4000;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;



            for (i = 0; i <= 4000; i++)
            {

                progressBar1.Value = i;

                int percent = (int)(((double)(progressBar1.Value - progressBar1.Minimum) /
 (double)(progressBar1.Maximum - progressBar1.Minimum)) * 100);
                using (Graphics gr = progressBar1.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                        SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont,
                        Brushes.Black,
                        new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                            SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Width / 2.0F),
                        progressBar1.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                            SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Height / 2.0F)));
                }


            }
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            random1();





                progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                progressBar2.Maximum = 3000;
                progressBar2.Visible = true;



                for (i = 0; i <= 3000; i++)
                {

                    progressBar2.Value = i;

                    int percent = (int)(((double)(progressBar2.Value - progressBar2.Minimum) /
     (double)(progressBar2.Maximum - progressBar2.Minimum)) * 100);
                    using (Graphics gr = progressBar2.CreateGraphics())
                    {
                        gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                            SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont,
                            Brushes.Black,
                            new PointF(progressBar2.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                                SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Width / 2.0F),
                            progressBar2.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                                SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Height / 2.0F)));
                    }

                }
                progressBar2.Visible = false;
                random2();    

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Search term you are looking for is [C# timer winforms](http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+timer+winforms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed your entire code and found that, you just need to refresh your page in random1() method. I have done Now It will show random no in label after completing your first progress bar in first label and second  random number will show in second label after completing second progress bar.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();              
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        progressBar2.Visible = false;
    }

     Random rnd = new Random();
     private void random1()
     {
        int t = rnd.Next(200);
        label1.Text = t.ToString();
        this.Refresh();
     }
     private void random2()
     {
        int t = rnd.Next(1500);
        label2.Text = t.ToString();
     }

     private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        int i;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 4000;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        for (i = 0; i <= 4000; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
            int percent = (int)(((double)(progressBar1.Value - progressBar1.Minimum) /(double)(progressBar1.Maximum - progressBar1.Minimum)) * 100);
            using (Graphics gr = progressBar1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                    SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont,
                    Brushes.Black,
                    new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                        SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Width / 2.0F),
                    progressBar1.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                        SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Height / 2.0F)));
            }


        }
        progressBar1.Visible = false;         
        random1();

            progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar2.Maximum = 3000;
            progressBar2.Visible = true;
            for (i = 0; i <= 3000; i++)
            {
                progressBar2.Value = i;
                int percent = (int)(((double)(progressBar2.Value - progressBar2.Minimum) / (double)(progressBar2.Maximum - progressBar2.Minimum)) * 100);
                using (Graphics gr = progressBar2.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    gr.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                        SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont,
                        Brushes.Black,
                        new PointF(progressBar2.Width / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                            SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Width / 2.0F),
                        progressBar2.Height / 2 - (gr.MeasureString(percent.ToString() + "%",
                            SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont).Height / 2.0F)));
                }

            }
            progressBar2.Visible = false;

            random2();                      

     }
```

Comment: Sir, I tried adding  this.Refresh(); in the random1(). But now it is not at all displaying any contents for labelbox1. the 2 progressbars will complete to 100% and then only the random number for labelbox 2 is displaying but nothing in labelbox1

Comment: SORRY... actually i missed to call the random1().....I got it.. it is working now... thanks a lot....you are my GURU.. :-)

Comment: Dear, 
No problem, finally you got your answer is important. Only thing is first you downvote so even though answer is correct but it shows downvote, If it is possible please change.

Comment: I did not do that...I tried to voteup.. but getting error as you require 15 reputations.. :-(